# Simplify: $X \cap (Z-X)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm a little confused as to what's the correct answer to this question - Yeah i'm a noob at math currently.

I have to simplify the following using the laws of set theory:

```
X(intersect)(Z-X);
```

Sorry for using text instead of proper notation. Just to clarify that is: X union the product of Y-Z;

**This is where i'm a little stuck**

The result of this is an empty set. However, i've been asked to simplify it not necessarily answer the question.

Would the answer to simplifying this be:

```
(X (union) Z) Complement
```

I don't know why but i'm unsure about that being correct. As I said, I'm a noob at math currently.

Thanks in advance

Comment: $X\cup(Z-X)=Z$, not the empty set.

Comment: Lol! Sorry, my mistake. It's intersection not union. My bad.
Edited.

Comment: I'd say you are certainly expected to answer $\emptyset$ then.

Comment: Does Z-X mean the complement of X in Z? If so, then Z-X is the set of all elements in Z that are not in X. So then it has no elements in common with X and so the intersection is empty.

Comment: Z-X is meant to be the difference between the two sets. My lecturer denotes this with a '-'. Though i'm sure it's a '\' .

Comment: @AlexBecker But that's answering the question, if i'm asked to simplify it would my answer be correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have, essentially, is (and the following is indeed, simplifying):

$$
\begin{align} x \in X\cap (Z \setminus X) 
& \iff x \in X \land (x \in Z) \land x\notin X \tag{1} \\ \\
& \iff (x \in X \land x\notin X) \land x\in Z\tag{2} \\ \\
& \iff x \in \varnothing \land x \in Z \tag{3} \\ \\
& \iff x \in (\varnothing \cap Z) \tag{4}\\ \\ 
& \iff x \in \varnothing \tag{5} \\ \\
& \;\;\therefore \quad X\cap (Z \setminus X) \equiv \varnothing.\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$

$(2) \iff (3):\,$ $$\varnothing = \{x\mid x\in X \land x \notin X\}$$

Comment: It shows that you can indeed simplify from $X \cap(Z - X)$ to $\varnothing$ because $X\cap (Z - X) \equiv \varnothing$, and shows steps you can use to justify that simplification.

Comment: Thank you for your time! That really helped

Comment: You're welcome, Fendorio!

Comment: Beautifully formatted too! +1

Answer (score 1):

Try using the fact that $Z\setminus X = Z\cap X^C$ (in your notation, $Z-X = Z\cap X^C$).  Then we have
$$
X\cap(Z\setminus X) = X\cap (Z\cap X^C) = X\cap (X^C\cap Z) = (X\cap X^C) \cap Z =\emptyset \cap Z = \emptyset.
$$